# Test for pattern A and B and return text lines in-between and including pattern A & B

Tags: bash, awk, grep, pattern-matching

Hello again stackoverflow!

I have a very large flat file which I am looking to export all records that match 2 different patterns.  The issue is the number of lines in each record is different and the records bleed into each other.  The last line of a record is Door ID, the first line is User: .

I am testing against @ in the email address and the last login contains 'login time: 2013-08'. I need to export all lines including the email address line and last login line. below are to 2 samples.  I have tried using awk like so:

```
awk '/login time: 2013-08/{e=0}/@ /{gsub("^.*@ ","",$0);e=1}{if(e==1){print}}'  filename
```

and of course that failed....

so here is the sample data

```
User: afshin@runners.org
First Name: Afshi
Last Name: Noghami
Is Delegated Admin: False
IP Whitelisted: False
Account Suspended: False
Must Change Password: False
Unique ID: 102209840259208897543
ID TPYE: Cx4
Creation Time: 2013-06-07T04:14:42.000Z
Last login time: Never
Path: /Members/Inactive

IMs:
Addresses:
Organizations:
Phones:
Relations:
Door IDs:
User: jjnalli@runners.org
First Name: JISS
Last Name: NALLIKUZHY
Is a Super Admin: False
Is Delegated Admin: False
Has Agreed to Terms: True
IP Whitelisted: False
Account Suspended: False
Must Change Password: False
Unique ID: 109765147242431344122
ID TYPE: Cx4
Mailbox setup: True
Included: False
Creation Time: 2013-06-07T03:32:52.000Z
Last login time: 2013-08-02T07:13:02.000Z
Path: /Members/Inactive

IMs:
Addresses:
Organizations:
Phones:
Relations:
Door IDs:
```

The desired output would look like below for each record that has a last login date:

```
User: jjnalli@runners.org  
First Name: JISS  
Last Name: NALLIKUZHY  
Is a Super Admin: False  
Is Delegated Admin: False  
Has Agreed to Terms: True  
IP Whitelisted: False  
Account Suspended: False  
Must Change Password: False  
Unique ID: 109765147242431344122  
ID TYPE: Cx4  
Mailbox setup: True  
Included: False  
Creation Time: 2013-06-07T03:32:52.000Z  
Last login time: 2013-08-02T07:13:02.000Z
```

Comment: Could you give us a sample of desired output?

Comment: adding desired output is being added to the original post now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this could work for you:

```
awk '$1=="User:",/login time: 2013-08/' file
```

Comment: unfortunately this did not remove any of the records that contained logins before 2013-08.  Thank you for contributing

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/User:/{if(NR!=1){for(i=0;i<j;i++)print a[i]>"file"k;j=0;k++;}a[j++]=$0;next}{a[j++]=$0;}END{for(i=0;i<j;i++)print a[i]>"file"k}' i=0 k=1  grepper.txt
```

where grepper.txt contains the input data

This will split the file into multiple files with one record (of course with multiple lines) per file.

Then grep and discard files that are not needed.

Inside a loop

```
grep "login time: 2013-08" fileN && grep "User:" fileN | grep "@" || rm -f fileN
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing, but this one liner errorred out.  Please see below.  This may be due to being on a Mac with Apples implementation of awk...                                                awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 /User:/{if(NR!=1){for(i=0;i<j;i++)print >>>  a[i]>"file"k <<< ;j=0;k++;}a[j++]=$0;next}{a[j++]=$0;}END{for(i=0;i<j;i++)print a[i]>"file"k}
awk: illegal statement at source line 1

Comment: I tested it in linux and worked well... may not be compatible for Mac :(

Answer (score 1):

#### Grouping lines from `^User` to `Door ID`, than print only if match `@.*login time: 20[0-9]`...

I think I've finally understood your need:

Try this:

```
sed -ne '/^Door ID/!H;/^User:/h;/^Door ID/{x;G;/@.*login time: 20[0-9]/p}' file
```

This will match your request.

Once each *packet* are merged, you could even drop all entries matching *2013-08*:

```
sed -ne '/^Door ID/!H;/^User:/h;/^Door ID/{x;G;/@.*login time: 20[0-9]/{/login time: 2013-08/!p}}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

First, read each record into an array of fields:

```
BEGIN { FS = ": " }   # each line has fieldname and value

/^$/ { next }         # skip blank records

$1 == "User" {        # first field of new record
    delete fields     # delete current array
    fields[$1] = $2 } # store field value in array

$1 == "Door IDs" {    # last field of current record
    fields[$1] = $2   # store field value in array
    do_process() }    # process current record

$1 != "User" &&       # fields between first ...
$2 != "Door IDs" {    #             ... and last
    fields[$1] = $2 } # store field value in array
```

Then, do whatever you need to do with the record. Here I print the User and Last login time fields, but you can do whatever processing you need:

```
function do_process() {
    print fields["User"], fields["Last login time"] }
```

Beware that I haven't tested this code ...

**EDIT:** Modified based on comment below. I assume that the User field always marks the beginning of a new record. Here's the revised version of the code to read and store a record:

```
BEGIN { FS = ": "       # each line has fieldname and value
        first = 1 }     # flag for first record

/^$/ { next }           # skip blank records

$1 == "User" {          # first field of new record
    if (first > 1)      # no data the first time; skip
        do_process()    # process current record
    delete fields       # reset fields for new record
    fields[$1] = $2 }   # store field value in array

$1 == "Door IDs" {      # last field of current record
    fields[$1] = $2     # store field value in array
    do_process() }      # process current record

/./ { fields[$1] = $2 } # store field value in array

END { if (first > 1)    # last record not processed
        do_process() }  # process last record
```

Then you can process the data however you like.

Comment: Thank you for assisting.  But our telecommuters do not have the Door ID field.... the only 3 common fields are Last Login, creation date and User:

Comment: Look at the modified version above.